# Strange compiled JS file from TypeScript & web pack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm migrating my plugin from gulp to webpack 2 and I have an issue with the completed js file.

the file is minified & compressed.

My web pack config file :

```
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
  entry: './src/ts/amt-rating.ts',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.tsx?$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader?tsconfig=tsconfig.json'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins:[
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        }
    })
  ]
}

//if production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.output = {
        filename: 'dist/js/amt-rating.min.js'
    }
    //uglify js options
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                minimize: true
            }
        })
    )


}
else{

    config.output = {
        filename: 'dist/js/amt-rating.js'
    }

    config.devtool = "#cheap-module-source-map"

}

module.exports = config;
```

And here my tsconfig file :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },

    "include": [
        "src/ts/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I wan't to compile my typescript into a very simple javascript file without any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This enables minification and compression:

```
//uglify js options
config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            screw_ie8: true,
            minimize: true
        }
    })
)
```

and is set to run if `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`. Make sure you have set it to `development` to get the not minified version.

Comment: I already tried to delete this options or to set false in dev environnement, the js file do not change

Comment: So it outputs a file called `dist/js/amt-rating.js` that is minified even when you remove the "production if" altogether?

Comment: Yes, minified and the var names are changed. I'am new to webpack and that I known, web pack is pushed from big ones like Facebook instead of gulp that seems to be more & more deprecated, so it's why I want to upgrade to webpack